# Handle REST service responses that contain invalid XML

Tags: java, xml, rest, apache-httpclient-4.x

I am retrieving user-entered data from a REST service. The data is returned in XML, so if a user has used a `<` character, my XML parse fails.

I'm using Apache `HttpClient` so I get the data as an `InputStream` and I don't think I can do anything with the data until I have it parsed as XML? I would have thought the service would be encoding these and would always return valid XML at least.

I found this out by writing the stream to a file instead of trying to parse it and this is the gist of the tag at the offending point:

```
<val>blah blah <100% blah blah</val>
```

So I'm not sure how to handle this.

Here's my code:

```
@Override
public DataSet handleResponse(final HttpResponse response) throws ClientProtocolException,
        IOException {
    final int status = response.getStatusLine().getStatusCode();
    if (status == 200) {
        final HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
        final DocumentBuilderFactory factory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
        try {
            final DocumentBuilder builder = factory.newDocumentBuilder();
            final Document doc = builder.parse(entity.getContent()); // exception
            // ...
```

The exception:

```
org.xml.sax.SAXParseException; lineNumber: 1; columnNumber: 2052; The content of elements must consist of well-formed character data or markup.
at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.DOMParser.parse(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.jaxp.DocumentBuilderImpl.parse(Unknown Source)
at javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilder.parse(Unknown Source)
```

Comment: Try to use CDATA in XML.

Comment: I'm not in control of the REST service.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is in the REST Web Service. If there is any String input, you need to cover your data with CDATA before you put into the websevice, I mean prepare your getTypedValue() method to do this. If the Webservice is not in your hand, that is a problem. Ask the developer to sole it.

If you want, you can make a http filter, read the REST XML and change it with CDATA and send back to the Webservice client side. But you should not do this. :)

Comment: Yeah, it's not my service so was not optimistic. Thanks.